# jQuery period in class name stored in var

Tags: jquery, class-names

I have this code:

```
var imgId = this.id; //file1.jpg
```

and this:

```
$('.img\\' + imgId).remove();
```

So the problem is, i cant escape the '.' because its in the var, not before. What can i do?

Comment: Your class is `.imgfile1.jpg`?

Comment: You have a `class` that contains the filename? Why? The `src` already contains the filename…

Comment: moreover the selector `'.img\file1.jpg'` will be interpreted as class `'img\file1'` and class `'jpg'`, ie class `'img\file1 jpg'`. "." (dot) is a class selector, ans should be escaped in ids or classes (as "#" and other "selectors" characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't store the filename as part of the class/id in your markup. Instead, use a data- attribute:

```
<div class="img" data-filename="file1.jpg" />
```

And then in your jQuery:

```
$('.img[data-filename="'+imgId+'"]').remove();
```

Comment: The `src` already contains the filename. Storing it anywhere else is redundant at best.

Comment: @Tomalak - Assuming you're working with an img element, yes. That's never specified in the post though. Could easily be working with an input/div/etc. related to an image (but not containing the image itself).

Comment: @Justin: Uhm, right. Could be. I would still do something like `$(".img[src$='"+filename+"']").closest("div.container").remove()` in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I've probably misunderstood the question - but, would this work?

```
$('.img\\' + replace(imgId,'.','\.')).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you do something like `$("#"+imgId, ".img").remove()`

Answer (score 0):

Use `.replace` to replace it.

```
var imgId = this.id.replace('.', '/.'); //Or whatever other escaping is there.
```

Answer (score 0):

While the period is a valid entity in an HTML Id I strongly sugest you follow a different naming convention, specifically one where periods are not used in Id values.